# Going from voting per district + census data, to voting per age?

Tags: inference

I have some voting or polling data that is listed by voting district. I also have detailed demographics of each voting district. How can I combine this to get an estimation of how the different demographics voted? I want to be able to make a chart of "percent yes" over age, or income bracket. (In the end, I want to use these relations to try and predict the outcome in a place with different demographics).

One approach I've seen is to treat it as a classification problem, and then assign each district input variables such as "% male", "% young" and so on. Then train a classifier, such as a BDT, and you can use it to predict voting outcomes for other demographics. The problem I see with this is that it treats the whole district as one data point. I can only indirectly get distributions of how the demographics voted. (For example see here: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-voting-outcomes-through-data-science-5d257b51ae5c)

I guess another approach would be to randomly generate data points in form of pseudo voters. The benefit would be that I could not only have single distributions (vote vs. age) but also multidimensional distributions (vote vs. age for different ethnicities). But I don't think the source data gives me that much information. And I would not even know how to create the pseudo data. It is probably prohibitively computationally expensive.

This seems like a very standard thing one wants to do, but I can't recall what the go to technique is. (The reverse, combining census data with voting per demographic to predict results in places seems straightforward.) Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't make progress here, there is just no data. Knowing how a district voted does not tell you how young vs old voted, even if you know how many young and old voters there are. The only available assumption is that they voted in line with the district %s. A classifier would reconstruct that answer; a simulation just tells you about the assumption you put in about age behavior.

Comment: But surely if districts with more old voters consistently have higher counts of "yes" (and assuming for simplicity age is the only factor) then we can infer that older voters were more likely to have voted "yes". We can't infer the causality, but if we have very many districts with sufficiently different population and voting behavior, we can surely reconstruct *some* information.

Comment: I think you're right, I didn't read/think through the setup correctly. It seems like a simple regression. % yes in district = (% old voting yes) * (% old in district) + (% young voting yes) * (% young in district) + noise. From the coefficients you get an estimate of rate of yes among old voters. For example.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will just try a regression when I have some time and post an answer if it worked. I find it hard to see intuitively if there is "enough information" in a problem not.